# Filter a dataframe within a UDF called with another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to do this:

1. Ingest data from 2 tables
2. Using the field SECONDS from table 1, find out which session it belongs to in table 2. So, if a session runs from 10:00 to 11:00 and the transaction in table 1 happened at 10:30, it would fit within that session.

The code I have is like below. I take the value from the table 1 and pass it into a UDF. Using that value, I want to be able to filter the other UDF to return the session number.

This doesn't work as I get this error.

```
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o73.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
```

Any ideas why this might be?

```
dpi_data = spark_session.sql("Select *, ((time_hour*3600) + (time_minute *60) + time_second) as seconds from table1 where hour = 04 and dt = " + yday_date )
dpi_sessions = spark_session.sql("select *, lead(seconds,1) over(partition by user order by seconds) as end_time from (select user, apn, ((time_hour*3600) + (time_minute *60) + time_second) as seconds from table2 where hour = 04 and dt = " + yday_date + ")x" )

def getsession(seconds):
    output = dpi_sessions.filter((dpi_sessions.start_time <= seconds) & (dpi_sessions.end_time >= seconds))
    print(output)
    return 'sss'

myudf = udf(getsession, StringType())
dpi_data = dpi_data.withColumn('apn', myudf(dpi_data.seconds))
```

The inputs are: Table1

[image]

Table2:
[image]

And the output is :
[image]

So here, we match the user to the correct session. Where the timestamp from table 1 is between the start and end times of table 2.

Comment: Could you please add some example data and the expected output? The problem that you see is that you reference within your udf function another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using UDFs wrong. You can't process a column value in a specific row (at a time) and reference another DataFrame somewhere else.

I believe the solution to your problem is that you have to `join` tables and then check to see which `seconds` belong to which session (occurring between a `start` and `end`).

Let's walk through it.

```py
# We set up the problem

# First DataFrame
dpi_data_columns = ["user", "seconds"]
data1 = [(272927, 31924), (272927, 32000), (272927, 45000), (272927, 78000), (272927, 79000)]
dpi_data_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data1)
# We rename user to user1 because to avoid column name duplicates post join 
dpi_data = dpi_data_rdd.toDF(dpi_data_columns).withColumnRenamed("user", "user1")
    
dpi_data.show()
#+------+-------+
#| user1|seconds|
#+------+-------+
#|272927|  31924|
#|272927|  32000|
#|272927|  45000|
#|272927|  78000|
#|272927|  79000|
#+------+-------+

# First DataFrame
dpi_sessions_columns = ["user", "start", "end", "key"]
data2 = [(272927, 15000, 40000, "Paid"), (272927, 40001, 86000, "Unpaid")]
dpi_sessions_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data2)
# We rename user to user2 because to avoid column name duplicates post join 
dpi_sessions = dpi_sessions_rdd.toDF(dpi_sessions_columns).withColumnRenamed("user", "user2")

dpi_sessions.show()
#+------+-----+-----+------+
#| user2|start|  end|   key|
#+------+-----+-----+------+
#|272927|15000|40000|  Paid|
#|272927|40001|86000|Unpaid|
#+------+-----+-----+------+
```

Okay so far so good. Now we simply join.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

join_condition = [dpi_data.seconds >= dpi_sessions.start, dpi_data.seconds <= dpi_sessions.end]
# We join and select target columns, renaming 'user1' or 'user2' back to 'user'
dpi_data_sessions = dpi_data.join(dpi_sessions, join_condition)\
     .select(col("user1").alias("user"), col("seconds"), col("key").alias("out"))

dpi_data_sessions.show()
#+------+-------+------+
#|  user|seconds|   out|
#+------+-------+------+
#|272927|  31924|  Paid|
#|272927|  32000|  Paid|
#|272927|  45000|Unpaid|
#|272927|  78000|Unpaid|
#|272927|  79000|Unpaid|
#+------+-------+------+
```

And that's the output you were aiming for, no UDF required.